# CSS3 issue with border-top and border radius

Tags: css

I am looking at adding a border-top, `20px solid red;`, and I want the bottom of this to be rounded. With the following it does seem to be working for me.

```
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 12px 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 12px 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px 12px;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does your box have a background?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't able to produce the result, but the above code looks correct. I've provided a JS Fiddle example, and mine works. I'm assuming you added the border-top property to the box. I don't think you need two values for each border-property. Hope this helps.

Create a new layer object with an ID of box and apply the following CSS. If you add a paragraph within the box the border will not appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/brownlace/kEvrE/1/embedded/result/

```
/* css3 rounded corners */

#box {
border-top: 20px solid red;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; 
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `border` instead of `border-top` to make sure the property is applied to all borders.

```
border: 20px solid red;
```

In this case you can use `border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;` with one value because both are the same.

Also you can add vendor property for webkit:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hbxzY/) is a fiddle.